# MongoDb sharding using $regex in sh.splitAt()

Tags: mongodb, sharding

The documentation for [sh.splitAt()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/sh.splitAt/index.html) sets no restriction on *query*, then why this leads to an error:

```
db.cases.createIndex({"code":1},{unique:true})
sh.shardCollection("casemanagement.cases",{"code":1})
sh.splitAt("casemanagement.cases",{code:{$regex:/...........[4-6]./}})
```

Error:

```
new split key {code:{$regex:/...........[4-6]./} is not valid for shard key pattern code {1.0}
```

Relevant 3.4 sources I found are *cluster_split_cmd.cpp* line 228, *shard_key_pattern_test.cpp*. Why does ShardKeyPattern care about the value side, since "code" is the shard key?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB sharding is based on chunk division. Each chunk has its defined max key and min key range. Hence the splitting is not surprising to accept only a range of values instead of regex pattern. I agree that this should be documented in sh.splitAt()

Answer (score 0):

I now understand what sh.splitAt() really does and how best to document it:

> ***sh.splitAt(namespace, query)*** splits the shard at a single **point** -- a query that identifies one and only one document that may or may not exist in the current collection, moving all documents beyond that **point** to the new chunk.

The feature I was looking for can be characterized as the following non-existent feature:

> ***sh.cull(namespace, filter)*** divides the shard using a filter query, where documents that selected by the query are moved to the new chunk, leaving those not selected by the query in the current chunk.